# hashtable datagridview show empty lines

Tags: c#, datagridview, hashtable

My Datagrid is filled with the right number of rows, but there are no data show.
All the row are display empty cols.

What could be the reason for that ?

[basedon](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/79420-bind-hashtable-into-datagridview/)

It is the first time I use a datagridview.

```
    public void BindDataGridView(DataGridView dgv, Hashtable ht) {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables.Add("test");

        //now build our table
        dt.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(Int32));

        IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = ht.GetEnumerator();

        DataRow row = null;

        while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
            string index = (string)enumerator.Key; // boekingsREf
            MyClass a = (MyClass)enumerator.Value;

            row = dt.NewRow();
            row["col1"] = index;
            row["col2"] = a.number;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        //dgv.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        dgv.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**First example**:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
    ht[1] = "One";
    ht[2] = "Two";
    ht[3] = "Three";

    BindDataGridView(dataGridView1, ht);
}

public void BindDataGridView(DataGridView dgv, Hashtable ht)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables.Add("test");

    //now build our table
    dt.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(string));

    foreach (DictionaryEntry dictionaryEntry in ht)
    {
        int index = (int)dictionaryEntry.Key;
        string value = (string)dictionaryEntry.Value;

        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row["col1"] = index;
        row["col2"] = value;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    dgv.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}
```

[image]

**Second example**:

Assuming your `MyClass` is

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int number { get; set; }

    static public implicit operator MyClass(int value)
    {
        return new MyClass() { number = value };
    }
}
```

and the hashtable is (reverse keys/values)

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
ht["One"] = 1;
ht["Two"] = 2;
ht["Three"] = 3;
```

and you change this line from your post code

```
MyClass a = (int)enumerator.Value;
```

[image]

Comment: Your example of course works however I couldn't find any thing wrong in the OP code. It should work and in fact I've tried the similar code and works like a charm. The OP might have something strange right in his testing, many kinds of such a question have been posted in SO.

Comment: Thanks for your help and time Tomek, I did it al over  from scratch, now it works perfectly.